# WKInterfaceTable scrollToRowAtIndex: scrolls to the wrong coordinate

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I have a WKinterfaceTable with several different row types. Each row should be "full screen", i.e. each row's container group has height "relative to container: 1".

I implemented a simple call to "re-center" the rows:

`- (void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    [table scrollToRowAtIndex:rowIndex];
}`

This works, but only if I am scrolling from a position *above* the tapped row. When I scroll upwards, it "overshoots" by a few pixels. Here are some pictures to illustrate what I mean:

This is the first row, after the interface is activated:

[image: First row in table]

If you tap "next", it scrolls to the second row just fine:

[image: Second row in table]

I can't prevent users from scrolling manually between the rows, so sometimes you can end up with something like this:

[image: In-between rows]

Tapping on the *lower* row re-centers the view correctly (like in picture 2), but tapping on the top row leads to this:

[image]

Another tap on the same row then correctly scrolls down a few pixels and we're back at picture 1.

Why does `scrollToRowAtIndex:` get the offset wrong only in one direction? Has anybody else experienced this problem before? Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you are trying to do.  Do you have three rows (or more) with row 1 having the circular numbers and row 2 having a picker and button, then a 3rd row with another circular number display?  Is there a reason you don't just have two rows so they don't scroll off the screen like in  your second picture?  --- ah, on re-reading, I think I understand better.  Why don't you just display one screen at a time, if that's what you want?  Why support scrolling at all?  It sounds like it won't give the proper behavior anyway.

Comment: @Cobra I don't think there's a way to disable scrolling in WKinterfaceTable, at least not that I've noticed?

Comment: Initially I had planned to implement this as a sequence of pages, but it turns out you can't present a paged interface, so the only option left was to have vertically scrolling views

Comment: While there isn't a paging controller, you can get similar behavior by either having multiple objects and hiding/showing them, or having display objects that you update the content in when you would otherwise have changed pages.